# Problem Axis Instance Points with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a problem with the axis on geometry nodes.
I instanced collection to cover the landscape. But I wanted the flowers cover the ground normal to my landscape, and I don't know why they are like this, on the side, and also below my landscape.

How I can fix this ?

Thank you for your help ! :D[image]

Comment: Looks like you either rotated your instancer plane or your flowers, you might need to apply the rotation with CTRL + A > Rotation

Comment: Oh yes, thank you !